# respondsToSelector and class_getInstanceMethod

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-runtime

Internally, does `respondsToSelector` do more than finding out if `class_getInstanceMethod` return non-nil?

Is respondsToSelector essentially a wrapper of class_getInstanceMethod? Like so:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)sel {
  return class_getInstanceMethod(self, sel) != nil;
}
```

Comment: In Apple's open-source [NSObject implementation](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/NSObject.mm), `respondsToSelector:` is on line 1472 and looks like this: `- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)sel {
    if (!sel) return NO;
    return class_respondsToSelector([self class], sel);
}`

Comment: Josh, this is awesome - the source.

Comment: To elebarate one step further on @JoshCaswell comment the actual implementation ends up in [objc-class.mm](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-class.mm) with `class_respondsToSelector` @ line 729, which calls through to `lookUpMethod` @ line 916 which is a good 99 line read

Comment: @JoshCaswell can you put your answer at the bottom?

Comment: Not much of an answer to my mind, but there you go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Apple's open-source [NSObject implementation](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/NSObject.mm), `respondsToSelector:` is on line 1472 and looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)sel { 
    if (!sel) return NO; 
    return class_respondsToSelector([self class], sel); 
}
```

`class_respondsToSelector()` in turn is on line 729 of [objc-class.mm](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-class.mm):

```
BOOL class_respondsToSelector(Class cls, SEL sel)
{
    IMP imp;

    if (!sel  ||  !cls) return NO;

    // Avoids +initialize because it historically did so.
    // We're not returning a callable IMP anyway.
    imp = lookUpMethod(cls, sel, NO/*initialize*/, YES/*cache*/, nil);
    return (imp != (IMP)_objc_msgForward_internal) ? YES : NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`-respondsToSelector:` returns a `BOOL` indicating, essentially, whether `class_getInstanceMethod()` would return a value.  Does that answer your question?

`-respondsToSelector:` paired with one of the variants of `-performSelector:*` is more idiomatic in conventional Objective-C code; it's rare to see (or to need) direct calls to the runtime.

**Edit**: the actual implementation is likely based on calling `class_respondsToSelector()`, but I expect that the implementation of that runtime method is not fundamentally different than your code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I elaborated the question more.

Comment: See update.  I think you've basically got it right. Though there are several ways the implementation could work, that's the basic logical function.

Comment: Actually I think there may be a subtle difference when forwarding is involved. If you implement a forwarding behavior (for instance to fake multiple inheritance) like described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html), you may end up with `respondsToSelector:` and `class_getInstanceMethod` to diverge.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella that document specifically points out that the standard implementation of `-respondsToSelector:` returns `NO` for a forwarded invocation.  If you follow the recommendation of overriding `-respondsToSelector:` for that situation, then yes, the behavior will diverge, but that's no surprise...

Comment: I know, what I'm talking about is that you if you change it to mirror your forwarding algorithm, you can unbind the result of the two methods. So you cannot rely that they will always return equivalent result, if you are not the owner of that class